# C# Unable to load types from dll at runtime

Tags: c#, dll

I need to get types of older dlls of my application.
I copied them to a local folder.
By running following code I always get a `System.TypeLoadException`

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            var subDir = Path.Combine(dir.FullName, "LegacyDlls");
            var aggregateRootDlls = Directory.GetFiles(subDir, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            var types= aggregateRootDlls.SelectMany(x => Assembly.LoadFile(x).GetTypes());
            return types.Where(t => t.BaseType?.Name == "AggregateRoot");
```

The type that cannot be loaded is declared in one of these dlls, though. I don't understand the error message.

Note that some of the loaded dlls still exist in my application with a newer version!
Is this causing the trouble? How do I workaround this?

UPDATE:
loading into another AppDomain did not help:

```
 var tempDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("temp");
            var types = rootDlls.SelectMany(x =>
                {
                    var assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(x);
                    return tempDomain.Load(assemblyName).GetTypes();
                });
            return types.Where(t => t.BaseType?.Name == "AggregateRoot");
```

Errormessage says

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
  ----> System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'Domain.SharedKernel.EventStreamer' from assembly 'Domain.SharedKernel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  ----> System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'Domain.SharedKernel.EventStreamer' from assembly 'Domain.SharedKernel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
```

Comment: Load DLL into another AppDomain (.Net Framework) or AsemblyLoadContext (.Net Core).

Comment: "I don't understand the error message." - well, *what did it say*? (yes, I can see that it says `TypeLoadException`, but the message might be useful too)

Comment: What is the actual use case? I would not expect that loading multiple versions of the same dll to work well, if at all. If the point is to load old objects serialized with binaryFormatter, then there are some possible workarounds that do not involve loading older dlls.

Comment: Is code using EventStreamer(see : https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/firepower/710/api/estreamer/EventStreamerIntegrationGuide/Intro.html?force_isolation=true).  You may need to have license for app for your code to run.

Comment: nope thats my own code...